# How to get a rectangle shape with no background color?

Tags: android

I want to get a rectangle `shape` with no `background color` but just the stroke line. What xml elements are concerned ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#1589FF" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

The background color is defined by the `<solid` tag, that you can set to transparent. To draw the border you can use `<stroke` tag

```
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/stroke_color" />
```